# Access External Volume Before Interactive Login

Tags: external-disk, launchd

We are running a node service that needs to access an external volume (USB HDD).

We've found that when we reboot the system and start the service via a plist in `/Libary/LaunchDaemons` our external volume is inaccessible to our service until we login interactively via Screen Sharing or VNC.

How do we configure our server in such a way that our external volume is accessible immediately upon restarting, and does not require an interactive login?

Comment: Is physical security at the remote location an issue? If not, try autologin.

Comment: @Tetsujin physical security is not, but remote security is. Will enabling autologin affect remote security at all?

Comment: This is something I do all the time at home - where I have no 'local attacker' worries at all. I use Apple's RDC & remote into the same user account as the active user. If the Mac is awake I just get straight in using my credentials already stored in RDC. if its screen timed out I additionally supply the password to wake the screen. I'd imagine if you set the screen to lockout after a very short time, that would be your vulnerable point as regards a local presence. [Unless you use the 'curtain' then the screen will wake anyway as you remote in & allow local interaction.]

Comment: In short, I don't see this as adding any inherent weakness to remote access, merely local access.

Comment: hi @Tetsujin, i believe auto-login fixed the issue for us. do you want to leave an answer so i can upvote it and accept it?

Comment: Will do - it's my end-of-day right now, so I'll come back tomorrow & try to come up with something coherent. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After comments -*
as physical security at the remote location is not an issue - ie, the machine would not be open to hands-on attack for the few minutes after boot, then autologin would allow a defined user to login automatically at boot, thereby enabling the required services.

[image]

This doesn't change the security requirement for remote access, so I would consider it 'safe'.